# Invalid IP Address

Tags: android, ip

I am trying to push data from android to mysql. It says Invalid IP address.
Why it happens? Is the problem is on the php code or the MainActivity of Java?

JAVA CODE:

```
`public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String name;
String id;
InputStream is=null;
String result=null;
String line=null;
int code;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText e_id=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Text1);
    final EditText e_name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Text2);
    Button insert=(Button) findViewById(R.id.but1);

    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        id = e_id.getText().toString();
        name = e_name.getText().toString();

        insert();
    }
});
}

public void insert()
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));

    try
    {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.shoaib.byethost9.com/insert.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
}
    catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}     

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
}
    catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
}     

try
{
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

        if(code==1)
        {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

PHP CODE:

```
enter code here<?php
$host='sql100.byethost9.com';
$uname='b9_14989725';
$pwd='';
$db='b9_14989725_android';


$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];

$flag['code']=0;

if($r=mysql_query("insert into android (id,name) values('$id','$name') ",$con))
{
    $flag['code']=1;
    echo"hi";
}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
```

?>

What is the problem? Why Invalid IP address?

Comment: What says invalid IP?  Android or the PHP?

Comment: When I run the app and try to send data to mysql

Answer (score -1):

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    setContentView(R.layout.xyz);
```